# Port forwarding won't work on Netgear JNR1010v2 router

Tags: router

I need to port forward my Netgear router 'JNR1010v2 genie' to my system. My ISP has assigned to my router a static IP of 172.17.1.x which I think is not my public IP. On googling my public IP is shown to be of the type 43.247.y.x. I made an entry on my router to forward port to 8080.[image: port forward page]

I have disabled all firewalls on my system and as far as possible on the router. I have a local server running on my system which I can access locally and on the local network. I ran a traceroute to my public IP from an external network and it did not complete. I am not able to ping this public IP. Is that normal?

Also I am attaching my WAN configuration page here [image: WAN page].

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Questions about configuring consumer-grade devices, questions about home networking, and questions from end-users of ISP networks are all specifically off-topic. You can ask these types of questions on Super User.

Comment: NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. Questions about home networks and consumer devices are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a 172.17(private) network in between you and the ISP then it won't work because they have to do some port-forwarding as well from the external IP to the one assigned to your router (I doubt they will).

The basic port forwarding config is ok as long as the internal IP and port number is correct.